# How to do class balancing?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

I am working with a **really imbalanced dataset** ($\approx$ 1% of positive cases) for a **classification problem**. I know that **class balancing** is an important step in this scenario.

I have two questions:

1. Considering that I don't want to put the 0/1 label, but just to order the record according to the output score (it is always a calibrated probability of being in the positive class), is it still a good idea to do class balancing or, considering the specific output required, it is useless?

   Basically, I do not care about the cut-off point, but I just sort the record in order to identify the one with a higher probability of being positives.
2. Considering the really small percentage of positive cases, is it better to do over/under sampling? Is there any rule-of-thumb to decide the proportion of resampling?

Thank you in advance!